# How do I define Azure Cosmos DB container composite indexes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create a container and define the composite indexes that I want using Azure Cosmos DB, Azure functions, and node with typescript. I have a config file that defines my options which I read from. I then try to pass in the composite index json object into my createIfNotExists containers function, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

config.ts

```
export const config = {
    endpoint: <MyUrl>,
    key: <MyKey>,
    databaseId: MyDBId,
    myContainerId: <MyContainerId>,
    myPartitionKey: { kind: "Hash", paths: ["/id"] },
    myContainerOptions:  {
      "compositeIndexes":[  
        [  
            {  
                "path":"/myId",
            },
            {  
                "path":"/myOtherId",
            }
        ]
      ]
    }
  };
```

my azure function code:

```
const myId= (req.query.myId || (req.body && req.body.myId));
  const myOtherId = (req.query.myOtherId || (req.body && req.body.myOtherId));
  const { endpoint, key, databaseId, myContainerId, myPartitionKey, myContainerOptions } = config;
  
  const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key});
  const database = client.database(databaseId);
  const container = database.container(myContainerId);
  
  await create(client, databaseId, myContainerId, myPartitionKey, myContainerOptions);
```

DbContext.ts

```
export async function create(client, databaseId, containerId, partitionKey, options?) {
    const { database } = await client.databases.createIfNotExists({ id: databaseId });
    const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: containerId, partitionKey}, options);
    console.log(`Created Database: ${database.id}\n Created container:\n${container.id}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite indexes should be part of container definition and not part of options.

Can you try with the following:

```
const containerDefinition = { 
  id: containerId, 
  partitionKey, 
  indexingPolicy: {
    compositeIndexes: [  
      [  
          { "path":"/myId"},
          { "path":"/myOtherId"}
      ]
    ]
  }
};
const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists(containerDefinition, options);
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error after partitionKey saying there should be a property assignment expected. I tried removing the braces before and after compositeIndexes, but it doesn't appear to have created the composite indexes since they're not showing in the Scale&settings option in the emulator. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I forgot to include `indexingPolicy` attribute. I have edited my answer. Can you please retry now?